# Manifest and abstract type resolution

Tags: scala, compiler-construction

I am hitting a compiler problem when the compiler needs to solve a manifest for a class with an abstract type parameter. The following snippet show the issue

```
trait MyStuff

trait SecurityMutatorFactory[X]{
  def apply(x1:X,x2:X)
}

object Example{

  trait LEdge[N]
  {
    type L1
  }
  type MyEdge[X] = LEdge[X] { type L1 = SecurityMutatorFactory[X]}

  val a:Manifest[MyEdge[MyStuff]] = implicitly[Manifest[MyEdge[MyStuff]]]

}
```

As a result, the compiler throws the following type error:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : scala.reflect.Manifest[LEdge[MyStuff]]
 required: Manifest[MyEdge[MyStuff]]
Note: LEdge[MyStuff] >: MyEdge[MyStuff], but trait Manifest is invariant in type T.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ >: MyEdge[MyStuff]`. (SLS 3.2.10)
  val a:Manifest[MyEdge[MyStuff]] = implicitly[Manifest[MyEdge[MyStuff]]]
```

What is happening at compiler level?                                             ^

Comment: By the way, you may safely remove SecurityMutatorFactory at all, and replace `L1 = Int` (or anything). It is not relevant to problem.

Comment: Also, if you replace `type MyEdge[X] = LEdge[X] { type L1 = SecurityMutatorFactory[X]}` by (equivalent?) `trait MyEdge[X] extends LEdge[X] { type L1 = whatever }` - it compiles.

Comment: Given two facts above, I feel the mistery is in the line `type MyEdge[X] = LEdge[X] { type L1 = SecurityMutatorFactory[X]}`, what does it exactly mean for compiler, that's the question.

Comment: The problem is that, as you can imagine, the edge has two nodes of type X. I want the label to be a function I can apply to both nodes...

Comment: Is there any particular reason for defining type alias for MyEdge rather than declaring trait or class MyEdge? it seems compiler just don't create manifest for such type alias. Though, the same as you I'd like to know the exact cause of error.

Comment: Yes. The real class LEdge is much more complex and I have simplified it for this question

Comment: regarding the labels and edges - it's not relevant for the type mismatch at all. You could refine the code that illustrates the problem to near the couple of lines: `object Example {
  trait A[T] {
    type L1
  }
  type B[T] = A[T] { type L1 = Any }

  val a: Manifest[B[Int]] = implicitly[Manifest[B[Int]]]
}`. It produces the same type mismatch and notice about type invariance in Manifest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have suggested the problem comes from

```
type MyEdge[X] = LEdge[X] { type L1 = SecurityMutatorFactory[X] }
```

Declarations of the form `type F[X] = ...` introduce type synonyms, ie new names for existing types. They do not construct new traits or classes. However, `LEdge[X] { type L1 = SecurityMutatorFactory[X] }` is constructing a new anonymous class. So your example is *approximatelly* equivalent to

```
trait MyEdge[X] extends LEdge[X] { type L1 = SecurityMutatorFactory[X] }
```

(which is what you most probably want) but the original definition in the example is defining a synonym for an anonymous class instead of defining a new class `MyEdge[X]`. So in the example the new class is not actually called `MyEdge`. When constructing the implicit manifest, the compiler replaces the type synonym with the underlying type, but fails to construct a manifest for that because that type is anonymous.

Replacing the `MyEdge` declaration with either a normal extension definition:

```
trait MyEdge[X] extends LEdge[X] { type L1 = SecurityMutatorFactory[X] }
```

or with an ordinary type synonym:

```
type MyEdge[X] = LEdge[X]
```

both compile successfully.

#### EDIT

Here is the specific reason why generating implicit manifests for anonymous classes fails.
In the language specification type expessions of the form `BaseType { ... }` are called refined types.
According to the language specification, the manifest for a refined type is just the manifest of its base class. This however fails to typecheck, because you asked for a `Manifest[LEdge[MyStuff]{ type L1 = SecurityMutatorFactory[X] }]`, but the algorithm is returning `Manifest[LEdge[MyStuff]]`. This means that you can only construct implicit manifests for types with refined types only in contravariant positions. For example using:

```
type MyEdge[X] = LEdge[X] { type L1 = SecurityMutatorFactory[X] } => AnyRef
```

in your example allows it to compile, though it is clearly not what you are after.

The full algorithm for constructing implicit manifests is given at the end of section 7.5 of the language specification. This question is covered by clause 6:

> 6) If T is a refined type T'{R}, a manifest is generated for T'. (That is, refinements are never reflected in manifests).

Answer (score 3):

Well, I'm not so familiar with that kind of pattern:

```
type MyEdge[X] = LEdge[X] { type L1 = SecurityMutatorFactory[X]}
```

but I tend to consider types defined with the `type` keyword as *aliases* (concepts) rather than a guarantee about the implementation (**EDIT** more precisely, I believe that `type` provides guarantees in terms of prototyping/specifying but that no AST/code is generated until there's an actual need to replace the alias with the traits/classes it's based upon). So even if the compiler claims, in its error message:

```
LEdge[MyStuff] >: MyEdge[MyStuff]
```

I'm not sure that, at the bytecode level, it implements `MyEdge` accordingly, with interfaces/methods/etc. Thus, it might not recognize the wanted relationship between LEdge and MyEdge, eventually:

```
found   : scala.reflect.Manifest[LEdge[MyStuff]]
required: Manifest[MyEdge[MyStuff]]
```

(and, is the absence of package `scala.reflect.` a hint? **(1)**)

About your code, how do you use `a`? Anyway, if the following is your intent, with:

```
trait MyEdge[X] extends LEdge[X] {
   type L1 = SecurityMutatorFactory[X]
}
```

instead, it does compile (scala 2.10)...  (**EDIT** I just noticed now that dmitry already told that) ...what that does during runtime, I don't know!

As an item of note, `Manifest` is deprecated after scala 2.9; so you may prefer to use `TypeTag[T]` as described in the scaladoc.

**EDIT:**
(1) I suspect that the following happens:
- at the syntactic analysis phase, the compiler registers **literally** what you specified, that is, the `implicitly` method *shall return* a `Manifest[MyEdge[MyStuff]]`.
- by the code generation phase, the aliases are **"reconciled" to their nearest** classes or traits; in the case of `implicitly` the result's type `Manifest[MyEdge[MyStuff]]` becomes trait `scala.reflect.Manifest[LEdge[MyStuff]]]`
- due to some limitations of type inference involved in `Manifest` and type "aliasing" within type parameters, however, somehow the specified requirement `Manifest[MyEdge[MyStuff]]` remains under its raw shape
- (this is pure conjecture, because I've not read the Scala compiler source code for this answer) the compiler would have the proper AST/code on the one hand, but a method prototype/spec that is still under its raw/literal shape on the other hand; that doesn't fit in so it emits an error.

Hoping that helps...